# Exportation of datas from Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm in an internship, and my cursus is mechanical engineering but my tutor asked me to make a little program to make some tasks quicker.
So here I am on the sites searching for tutorials but I've got some questions.

I've got an Excel File built that way
[ExcelFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0VLF.jpg)

So basically I have pieces and those piece are either on 2 or 3 rows.
I have to extract the datas of each piece to make my calculations afterwards.
I started to write my code but I'm a little stuck, so here how it goes

```
    Dim Exel As Excel.Application
    Dim nbrePieceUni As Integer
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim Range As Excel.Range
    Dim xWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Range = xWorksheet.UsedRange

For i = 2 to Range.Rows.Count
    #If xWorksheet.Cell(i,1) <> xWorksheet.Cell(i-1,1) Then
        nbrePieceUni = nbrePieceUni + 1
#Else
    'something which count the number of lines in each piece

Next i
```

I started write it in VB because I know a little about it but on many sites, I read about OLEdb but I don't know how to do this.

Can someone tell me if I should go on with my code or try OLEdb?
Either way, how can I write this so I can use each data for calculation after?

If you need more explanations, I'd be glad to explain in a better way

Best Regards
N

Comment: to my knowledge if you are exporting data from vb.net to excel then I do believe you cannot use OLEdb. if you are importing excel to vb.net OLEdb is the way to go

Comment: Well, I've got my datas on an Excel File, and I want to use those informations to make my calculations after.
So I want to extract the datas from the Excel file, make my calculations and after make what I have to do

Comment: So are you exporting data to excel using - doing stuff in excel and then importing into vb.net?

Comment: Hum, this is more like this:
Entry Datas on Excel => Export those datas into my VB program => Calculation on my program => suite of my program

Comment: Ahhh - I think you really mean import into your VB.net Program and then do calculations. Because you are a student I would rather not post the code to do this however I would use the OLEdb - here is an http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_oledb.htm

Comment: Yes sorry, english is not my first language :/
I already seen this thread but I had some trouble because the example given is littler than my excel file + I have to import the datas not all at the same time.
In the link, I think it takes all the table at once.
How can I take only one column at first?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do it that way but instead of using select * from [Sheet1$]  - do select yourColumnNameIn_Excel from [Sheet$1]

Comment: Because I have several conditions before my calculation. So if I have 2 lines for 1 piece, how can I make it into 1 entity?
Like: if I make a MsgBox item(193) it's supposed to give me all the datas of the piece 193 (which is on the excel file is on 2 lines)

Comment: This is what I would do, after you import your whole excel file into your datatable, I would then do calculations and validation on the datatable itself , ie messageboxes and if conditions